# How to Keep Track User Last Activity Time Using Microsoft.AspNet Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity-2

So I've extended default User class as ;

```
[Serializable]
public class AUser : IdentityUser<int, AUserLogin, AUserRole, AUserClaim>, IUser , IXmlSerializable
{
    public virtual DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

And I've a method to update user activity

```
 public async void UpdateUserActivity(string userName)
 {
     var user =  _userManager.FindByName(userName);
     user.LastActivity = DateTime.UtcNow;
     await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
 }
```

My purpose here is to keep track of last activity time of users. By last activity time i mean the last time  user did any action on the application.

I was planning to call the update method after each request is executed. However, it means executing an update on the database for each request. That sounded expensive to me.

**Question** : where shall i call it? Is there any better way to keep track of user last activity?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [OnActionExecuted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) event inside a controller to keep track of the user activity and write the activity log for all users into an application wide object using `HttpContext.Application`. To keep the traffic to your database low you could implement a global background thread, that reads the local stored activity data and writes them into youir database after a fixed time (e.g. once per minute).

You would have less database traffic, but the activity data would not be 100% up to date. Depending on your database update cycle.

Comment: Sounds much better solution. Will do this way. Thanks.